# Prove that $\Delta KML$ is isosceles triangle.

Tags: geometry, circles

Let $\Delta ABC, \angle BCA=90^o$  draw $CH$ is  perpendicular to $AB$ at $H$, the circle $A$ with AC is radius and the circle B with BC is radius. $I$  is chosen arbitrarily in $CH$. $AI\cap (B,BC)={K,Q} (\text {K}\in AI)$ and $BI\cap (A,AC)={L,P} (\text {L}\in BI)$ and $BK\cap AL={M}$ . Prove that $\Delta KML$ is isosceles triangle. 
[image]

---

I proved that $PKLQ$ is cyclic quadrilateral

Then i will prove $\angle LKM=\angle MLK$

Or i will prove it by trigonometric $\sin \angle LKM=\sin \angle MLK$ but failed.